# Change polygon color programmatically of a digitized image

Tags: c#, winforms, arcgis, satellite-image

I don't have knowledge about ArcGIS... But I am working on a program related to that...

I have to do-

- Load digitized image in my windows application  and after that i have to change polygon color according to client need.
- Actually the image is a satellite/drone image, and in ArcGIS my colleague plotting polygons.
- I have to load that digitized image in windows application and according to requirement (like differentiate polygons according to area; polygon having area between 0 to 1000 sq.ft. must be in yellow;between 1001 to 1500 - red; etc) I have to change that polygons color programmatically using C#

So my question is, In which format that digitized image must be? so that i can change polygon color...

One more thing I didn't tried anything to accomplish this... Because I don't know about this... So feel free to suggest any relevant solution....

**EDIT**:
Here are the to images, one is before digitizing and another is a demo of after digitizing

[image: Before Digitization]

[image: A dummy of digitized image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: So what are those polygons? Do have them or shall you find them? In what form do you have them? What about the images? Which format(s) do they ahve? Can you show an example?

Comment: Actually in ArcGIS they are plotting polygon for house on Orthomosaic image... I think images in Raster/GeoTiff format... Please Check Question Again I Edited and added images in that